# Preselect select element which is preloaded using ajax

Tags: jquery

I have a select element which its options are populated using ajax calls, on success of ajax call,
i set my index to -1, which means the select will not show the :selected as default

my jquery on success of ajax call is

```
$("#brandList").prop("selectedIndex", -1);
```

so my select box which looks something like this

```
<select id="1">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>
```

How do I use jquery to preselect the option? for example on load i want it to show option b. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('select option:contains(b)').prop('selected', true);
```

(in your Ajax success callback)

Comment: `[value="b"]` will only match if the `[value]` *attribute* is exactly equivalent to `b`. The provided HTML does not have the `[value]` attribute set for any `<option>` elements.

Comment: yea i tried that and it comes up with this error Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #brandList option[value=Brooks Brothers]

Comment: Well, if you don't have a value attribute (you should), use `:contains`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:eq(index)](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq) selector that matches a single element by its index.

```
 $('#select option').eq(1).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

**Note :** Index is zero-based.